# Google DNS Vs SmartDNS

Tags: dns

What is the difference between a normal Public DNS Server like  Google DNS and a SmartDNS?

Comment: This is really not related to programming at all. At a first glance, both services are functionally similar, but marketed very differently.

Answer (score 0):

They both are 2 different companies offering the DNS resolution services. Basic work of DNS service provider remains the same across the companies which is resolving a domain to the correct IP address, but the way they do this varies based on each companies implementation.